# How to automatically call all functions in C source code

Tags: c, linux, code-generation, automated-tests

have you ever heard about automatic C code generators?

I have to do a kind of strange API functionality research which includes at least one attempt of every function execution. It may lead to crushes, segmentation faults - no matter. I just need to register every function call.

So i got a long list (several hundreds) of functions from sources using

```
ctags -x --c-kinds=f *.c
```

Can i use any tool to generate code calling every of them? Thanks a lot.

**UPD**: thanks for all your answers.

Comment: Won't some of these functions have parameters, how will you be generating them? It seems like you want to automate testing but are trying to do it without actually creating tests.

Comment: Perhaps you could code some `awk` or Python script piped into `ctags`  output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also consider customizing the GCC compiler, e.g. with a [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension (which e.g. would generate the testing during some customized compilation). Then you might even define your own `#pragma` or `__attribute__` to parameterize these functions (enabling their auto-testing, giving default arguments for testing, etc etc).

However, I'm not sure it is the right approach for unit testing. There are many unit testing frameworks (but I am not very familiar with them).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like autoconf could help you with that: [as described here](http://openbooks.sourceforge.net/books/wga/creating-configuration.html). In particular check for AC_CHECK_FUNCS. Autoconf creates small programs to test the existence of registered functions.

Comment: Thank you, nice idea, but are you sure that Autoconf really tries to call the functions, not only check if the small programs very just built?